# Anylogic: Local Database Connection

Tags: java, database, anylogic

I'm really struggeling here. Anylogic gives me the Database Connection Problem for some days now and the support was not able to help me until now

[image: Screenshot1]

What I got here is a windows mashine running the latest Win10 with Anylogic 7.3 Professional

My Anylogic Model is completely local and runs perfect until I try to add an Database Table. As mentioned above Anylogic asks me reconnect the database each time I try to insert a table. Pressing the Connect button does nothing, but showing the same window again. Pressing cancel shows me the following error message:

[image: Screenshot2]

Together with the Anylogic Support I already tried to disable the Antivirus, send them logs,etc. Nothing helped so far. I already tried to reinstall the whole program including a thourough clean (all .Anylogic Folders, files,...).

I don't know anymore what else to do at this point. I hope any of you guys can help out a little.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-12-21 13:48:02.168
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection timed out
    at com.anylogic.objectmodel.commands.database.AbstractDatabaseCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.objectmodel.commands.CompoundCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.objectmodel.commands.BasicCommandStack.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.objectmodel.commands.CommandStack.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.properties.widget.WidgetBuilder$86.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.properties.widget.WidgetBuilder$86.onAdd(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.properties.widget.base.list.ListWidget.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.components.button.ButtonDecorator.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.components.button.ButtonDecorator.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at com.anylogic.application.AnyLogicApplication.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection timed out
    at com.anylogic.database.DatabaseManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.database.DatabaseManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.database.DatabaseManager.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.database.DatabaseManager.createColumn(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.database.DatabaseManager.createColumn(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.objectmodel.commands.database.CreateColumnCommand.doExecute(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: Would be useful to see code, I guess. Or, what exactly makes this a Java question is unclear other than the exception message, which is only a software problem that the support team can help you with. Otherwise this belongs on [su]

Comment: I adde the java tag as Anylogic is based on java and the second screenshot throws some java exeption

Comment: "some Java exception" isn't really answerable here. You have a networking issue, that's all we can tell

Comment: I added a part of the log file, maybe that helps, the only thing I can read from it is that it lost the connection. But the thing is that I don't understand how I can loose the connection when everyting is local and the same folder as the rest of the model, which works

Comment: The server isn't running? You connect to the wrong port number? Your firewall or anti virus is otherwise blocking the connection? There's lots of things to check for that error

Comment: Patrick, did you try to execute this command in Windows CMD — "telnet localhost 9001". What are the results? It requires the telnet client to be enabled in Windows 10. Here is instructions: https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-enable-the-telnet-client-in-windows-10/

Comment: Patrick, since this isn't a forum, you should not update the question to "SOLVED". You instead can answer below, or tell @TatianaGomzina to give the answer

Answer (score 3):

I have also run into this problem. If you go into the database folder of the model and delete the lock file and the previous database folder it will open without throwing that error.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I don't know exactly why it occurred, but something with storing the Model went wrong. But I managed to reconnect with the following procedure:

1. Copy the whole folder of the Project and store it somewhere
2. In the new folder delete the .original.alp-File
3. Rename the .alp-File
4. then open the Renamed .alp-File in an text-editor

In that file you'll find something like that:

```html
*************************************************
          AnyLogic Project File 
*************************************************          
-->
<AnyLogicWorkspace WorkspaceVersion="1.9" AnyLogicVersion="8.5.1.201910011746" AlpVersion="8.4.9">
<Model>
 <Id>1570541727194</Id>
 <Name><![CDATA[20191030-02-SBB-DAT]]></Name>
 <EngineVersion>6</EngineVersion>
 <JavaPackageName><![CDATA[_20191008_02_sbb_dat]]></JavaPackageName>
 <ModelTimeUnit><![CDATA[Minute]]></ModelTimeUnit>
 <ActiveObjectClasses>
  <!--   =========   Active Object Class   ========  -->
```

Now find **all Strings in that file** equals to the packageName, in my case:

_20191008_02_sbb_dat

and replace it with the name of your .alp file, in mycase:

sbb_dat.

It should look like this:

```html
<AnyLogicWorkspace WorkspaceVersion="1.9" AnyLogicVersion="8.5.1.201910011746" AlpVersion="8.4.9">
<Model>
 <Id>1570541727194</Id>
 <Name><![CDATA[SBB-DAT]]></Name>
 <EngineVersion>6</EngineVersion>
 <JavaPackageName><![CDATA[sbb_dat]]></JavaPackageName>
 <ModelTimeUnit><![CDATA[Minute]]></ModelTimeUnit>
 <ActiveObjectClasses>
  <!--   =========   Active Object Class   ========  -->
```

After that store and close the file and open it with AnyLogic. In my case this helped.

Answer (score 1):

When the db connection fails after adding the first table to the model, I’d suggest checking if some application isn’t using the hsqldb port (9001). You could use Sysinternals [tcpview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) to check that. In my case, Nvidia broadcast application took the port and broke db connections in all of my models.

Also, Anylogic db breaks when something is locking the db files. I’d suggest storing the models outside of cloud synced folders, and add antivirus exceptions to exclude the 'Models' folder from background scanning.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error and solved as follow:
(Inspired on @cogijl answer)

1. Close the model and Anylogic.
2. Go to the model folder and delete the folder "database".
3. Open the model. This will generate the error again but with something different: you can now add or delete databases (tables) in the database section.
4. Delete the database with the option "Delete database" in the Database section.
5. Add the tables again with the option "Create or Import table..."
6. Make sure you import the tables using the same names as before, otherwise everything will crash.
7. Done, the model runs again.

the only thing you will lose, is the Export setting, but it's easy to set them again.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting all Anylogic relevant rules. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with rules?

Answer (score -1):

According to the result of listening localhost 9001, something blocked the connection between AnyLogic and Server DB. Deleting all rules defined for Anylogic (though all of them were „permit“) helped.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with rules?